# sparsest cut always has solution

Tags: linear-programming, approximation-algorithms

Hi!

How to prove that sparsest cut always has an optimal solution which is the cut for some vertex-subset.

Looks like it's should be a kind of fundamental theorem for sparsest cut. But I didn't remember something like this for multicut and multicommodity flow.

Can you give me a hint how to prove this.

Thanks!

Comment: What is a sparset cut? Did you mean sparsest cut? 

Comment: WHat does the question mean? What is "the cut for some vertex subset"?

Comment: I need to prove that there is always for any instance of the sparsest cut problem exists optimal solution which is cut $(S,\overline{S})$ for some vertex subset $S \subset V$

Comment: As opposed to what? What other kind of cuts are there?